# Ubuntu 19.04 sudo apt-get update throws an error

Tags: apt

I've been looking everywhere, but I haven't been able to find the error that looks like mine. My computer is definitely connected to the internet.

```
Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Ign:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                                       
Ign:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                                     
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco InRelease                                          
Hit:5 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                  
Err:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release                                                 
  404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
Hit:7 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                   
Err:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
Err:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release                                       
  404  Not Found [IP: 2403:8940:ffff::f 80]
Ign:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease                                       
Err:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release                                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kdenlive/kdenlive-stable/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kgilmer/speed-ricer/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mkusb/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/neovim-ppa/stable/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/scribus/ppa/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu disco InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 19.04 _Disco Dingo_ - Release amd64 (20190416)]/ disco main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse

# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse

deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco edge stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable edge
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable edge
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list 
- putting this out there because I saw others do it

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL or *end-of-life* (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/01/23/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-23-2020/) thus off-topic on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) unless your question is specific to help moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Use a LTS or *long-term-support* release if you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Your issue is the EOL status of your release, the repositories aren't there anymore (due EOL) and have moved to old-releases; refer my prior comment and the EOLUpgrades link.  (a duplicate link on this site will also show in time)

Comment: Ah! Apologies... Didn't know that... Will take the question down...